# "Too Much Recursion" Problem

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm helping a company develop a website that utilizes jquery but I have noticed that the site slows to a complete halt with a jquery "Too Much Recursion" error. The company really needs to get this resolved but retain the slideshow capabilities as they are right now. Here is the code in question:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $testimonialCont;
var $slideshowContainer;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $slideshowContainer = $('.slideshowContainer');
  var inititalSlideshowDelay = setTimeout(cycle_slideshow_image, 4000);

  $testimonialCont = $('.testimonialContainer');
  $('.testimonialBubble').hide();
  $('.testimonialBubble').removeClass('hide');
  cycle_top_bubble()
  var initialTestimonialDelay = setTimeout(cycle_top_bubble, 3000);
});

function cycle_slideshow_image(){

  //This code cycles the slideshow caption headings and body text
  $('h1.slideshowCaptionHeading:last').fadeOut(1500, function(){
    $(this).prependTo('.captionHeaderArea');
    $(this).show(1);
     var delay = setTimeout(cycle_slideshow_image, 4000);
   });
  $('p.slideshowCaptionBody:last').fadeOut(1500, function(){
    $(this).prependTo('.captionBodyArea');
    $(this).show(1);
    var delay = setTimeout(cycle_slideshow_image, 4000);
  });

  $('img.slideshowSlide:last').fadeOut(1500, function(){
    $(this).prependTo($slideshowContainer);
    $(this).show(1);
    var delay = setTimeout(cycle_slideshow_image, 4000);
  });

}

function cycle_top_bubble(){
  $('.testimonialBubble:last').prependTo($testimonialCont).fadeIn(1500, function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var thisTimer = setTimeout(function(){
      $this.fadeOut(1500, function(){        
        var thisDelay = setTimeout(cycle_top_bubble, 3000);
      })
    }, 5000);
  });
}
</script>
```

Here is the site's address: http://dbunderdevelopment.com/CRR/

If anyone has any suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it.

P.S. I did post this question before as an unregistered user and I sincerely apologize in advance for that. I can't seem to find the post in order to delete but, rest assured, it will not happen again. I know how bad repostings are on forums.

Comment: It might be a little easier to debug if you used the non-minimized version of jQuery.  I can see the recursion happening but the code is too cramped to decipher.

Comment: I see what you mean. I changed it to the non-minimized version to make it more readable.

Comment: Don't forget to change it back when you are ready to release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it looks like `cycle_slideshow_image` calls itself three times each time it is called... change it to this:

```
function cycle_slideshow_image(){

  //This code cycles the slideshow caption headings and body text
  $('h1.slideshowCaptionHeading:last').fadeOut(1500, function(){
    $(this).prependTo('.captionHeaderArea');
    $(this).show(1);
   });
  $('p.slideshowCaptionBody:last').fadeOut(1500, function(){
    $(this).prependTo('.captionBodyArea');
    $(this).show(1);

  });
  $('img.slideshowSlide:last').fadeOut(1500, function(){
    $(this).prependTo($slideshowContainer);
    $(this).show(1);
    var delay = setTimeout(cycle_slideshow_image, 4000);
  });

}
```

Also, `cycle_top_bubble` is being called twice initially, so it's running in two loops. remove this line:

```
var initialTestimonialDelay = setTimeout(cycle_top_bubble, 3000);
```

Another thing to consider is that when your page becomes an inactive tab in the browser, the timeouts are clamped to 1000ms ([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout)) so the animation may build up if you have the timeouts too short, which you don't, but it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: You're absolutely correct; there were too many function calls which led to that "Too Much Recursion" error. Initially, I was thinking there were no callbacks from the setTimeout functions but I was only confusing myself on what setTimout actually does. I did see that "clamped" setTimeout bug mentioned in a Mozilla article at one time. Also, I removed the first cycle_top_bubble reference as it seemed out of place (still needed the initial setTimeout function for the testimonials). Anyways, sorry for the rant. Thank you so much for your time, fudgey.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to think about how recursion works, when you recurse in those set timeout functions you create a new scope inside the recursed function,  Adding everything onto the stack without popping off the last function.

If you look at this as it is a block of memory but you never recurse which is the returning back up you continue to flood memory with more and more objects until its full.  How you can solve this is pretty easy.

First recursion is the wrong approach for something that never completes, I explained why above. The recursion needs to be changed.  The solution I would use is have a callback on the setTimeout but move your setTimeouts outside the scope of the calling function. This should help with the memory problem.

Other suggestions is to use a real slideshow plugin that someone else wrote... I know this may be frowned upon but why recreate the wheel when it has been done 1000 times. I recommend [jQuery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) it is extremely fast and customizable.

Good luck!

Comment: Actually, I believe the callback for the setTimeout function is the 4 second delay. The problem is that they had three setTimeout functions all with 4 second delays called from another setTimeout function with its own 4 second delay (if I'm accurate on saying this). This means the recursive calls outweighed the callbacks. In essence, you were correct that the callback on the setTimeout functions needed to change. I just didn't know how to go about getting it done. Thank you for taking the time in helping me out, austinbv.